# Associated models and SUM query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, sum

I've got two Rails models, a Child and a Parent say.

I know that I can do this:

```
Child.sum(:income, :conditions => "parent_id = #{@parent_id}")
```

But I want to be able to do this:

```
Parent.children.sum(:income)
```

But this is giving me the wrong values if I try it. Is there a more concise way of writing

```
Child.sum(:income, :conditions => "parent_id = #{@parent_id}")
```

?

TIA

[ps: Rails 3 dev environment]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry but I have just found out the answer to this. I needed to add to_a to the collection of Child objects, and call a proc, as so:

```
Parent.children.to_a.sum(&:income)
```

This works a charm.

Comment: try this with a million records

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for bumping up an old thread, but I think I found better(best?) solution. Below is code for my project that I ended up

```
self.purchases.where(:script_id => script_id, :approved => true).sum(:instances)
```

It produces one query that does exactly what I need

```
SELECT SUM("purchases"."instances") AS sum_id FROM "purchases" WHERE "purchases"."customer_id" = 1 AND "purchases"."script_id" = 1 AND "purchases"."approved" = 't'
```

Comment: I have to say I like this idea of this taking place in the model a little better

Answer (score 3):

I ran into an issue where the child was delegating to the parent and I needed to find a sum.

```
children.to_a.sum(:parent_income)
```

was giving me a major N+1 problem. The solution was to use:

```
children.joins(:parent).sum(:income)
```